# divergence rate of $\sum_{n=1}^k\frac{1}{1+n\log n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is it possible to get a growth rate bound for the partial sum $\sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{1}{1+n\log n}$? For instance for the harmonic series  we have two bounds:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{1}{n} \leq \ln k +1 \text{ and } \sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{1}{n}> \ln(k+1) $$

Are there bounds like this possible for the mentioned sum?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ever heard of comparison between integral and series ? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence). Partial sums are equivalent to $\sum \limits_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{k \mathrm{ln}(k)}$ and the corresponding integral is easy to compute

Answer (score 4):

$\frac{1}{1+n\ln n}\sim \frac{1}{n\ln n}$. Compare with an integral, and use equivalence of partial sums of divergent series :
$$\sum_{k=2}^N \frac{1}{1+n\ln n} \sim \int_2^N \frac{dt}{t\ln t} = \left[\ln(\ln t)\right]_2^N \sim \ln(\ln N)$$

Comment: thanks, thats what i got too

Answer (score 1):

Compare it to $\sum_2^\infty 1/(n \log n)$ and assuming it converges, use the integral test.

This series converges if and only if the following integral converges
\begin{equation}
\int_2^\infty \frac{1}{x \log x} dx = \left[\log(\log x)\right]_2^\infty
\end{equation}
which clearly diverges...

Comment: thanks for the answer, but dont need divergence claim, already knew it